# Is it good practice to #include a library that is already included is another library?

Tags: c++

In C++, I want to make use of some functions from the  library and I noticed that my code compiles without including the header of that library, because the  library is indirectly included in the  library that I already included it's header in my project.

Should I leave it like this or is it good practice to #include  as well, just to show to other people that are reading my code from where the functions I am using are coming from?

Comment: *"Is it good practice..."* Seems opinion based.

Comment: Include the headers in a source file if they are needed in that source file. This should be simple/straightforward enough.

Comment: you dont `#include` libraries, but headers. The question is unclear.

Comment: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Include_What_You_Use

Comment: @user12002570 I agree with you. However "needs the header" is often misinterpreted as "does not compile without including the header", which is something entirely different. That difference and the difference between "including a header", "using a library" and between "compiling" and "building" are things that beginners often confuse, until they learn it. Usually the frustrating and/or hard way. So please be careful with your phrasing, yoou might want to contrast in order to make your meaning of "need" clear.

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks a lot. Couldn't find any valid documentation easily. The Google C++ style guide seems valid enough.

Comment: once you included a header, including it again does no harm, hence its nothing to worry about. If you want to reduce number of includes you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration. Though, if you do use something from a header, you should include it even though it is already indirectly included (that bit is somewhat opinion based, but I actually never heard someone in favor of a different one)

Comment: On top of Google style guide, it is also a Cpp Core guideline: See [SF.10](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#SF-source-files), for the same reason.

Comment: It's also good practice because what's included is an implementation detail and can be changed at any time: https://godbolt.org/z/1zMjfxEon (Unless it's part of the explicitly defined transitive includes, like `<utility>` includes `<initializer_list>`, or `<iostream>` includes `<istream>`)

Comment: The problem here, which is already demonstrated by earlier comments, is that if you ask ten C++ developers "is <X> a good practice" you are guaranteed to get at least eleven different answers/

Comment: Include what you use.  If your code does not use `std::vector`, your code should not `#include <vector>`.  Vice versa, if your code does use `std::vector`, your code should directly `#include <vector>`, and **not** rely on `#include "Foo.hpp"` doing a `#include <vector>` for you.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai "*once you included a header, including it again does no harm*" - provided that it uses proper guards to prevent conflicts from multiple inclusions. Standard headers do. MOST 3rd party headers do, but there's always the possibility that someone forgets to do it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would think that it is standard practice to implement proper guards such as `#pragma once` nowadays. And using that as an argument to not explicitly include the headers you need for YOUR code, I simply cannot get behind. But that is perhaps not what you are implying in the first place. And you are making a good point, pointing it out. Without proper guards, you could run into issues when including a header more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that what you are trying to ask is if it is good practice to explicitely include headers even if they have already been transitively included through another include.

**Short answer**: Yes. Libraries change, and so does what they include, and if you do not have control over the includes you need for your code, you will most likely run into problems down the road.